# How to map the differences between two strings?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I came across the following question and was wondering what would be an elegant way to solve it.
Let's say we have two strings:

```
string1 = "I love to eat $(fruit)"
string2 = "I love to eat apples"
```

The only difference between those strings is `$(fruit)` and `apples`.
So, I can find the fruit is apples, and a `dict{fruit:apples}` could be returned.

Another example would be:

```
string1 = "I have $(food1), $(food2), $(food3) for lunch"
string2 = "I have rice, soup, vegetables for lunch"
```

I would like to have a `dict{food1:rice, food2:soup, food3:vegetables}` as the result.

Anyone have a good idea about how to implement it?

**Edit**:

I think I need the function to be more powerful.

```
ex.
string1 = "I want to go to $(place)"
string2 = "I want to go to North America"

result: {place : North America}

ex.
string1 = "I won $(index)place in the competition"
string2 = "I won firstplace in the competition"

result: {index : first}
```

*The Rule would be*: **map the different parts of the string and make them a dict**

So I guess all answers using str.split() or trying to split the string will not work. There is no rule that says what characters would be used as a separator in the string.

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference to some of the answers, but I assume you need to handle foods with compound names.  i.e. ‘clam chowder’

Comment: @JLPeyret You are correct, I am not expect to split the string into different parts since white space is not always a separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to replace `$(name)` with `(?P<name>.*)` and use that as a regex:

```
def make_regex(text):
    replaced = re.sub(r'\$\((\w+)\)', r'(?P<\1>.*)', text)
    return re.compile(replaced)

def find_mappings(mapper, text):
    return make_regex(mapper).match(text).groupdict()
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> string1 = "I have $(food1), $(food2), $(food3) for lunch"
>>> string2 = "I have rice, soup, vegetable for lunch"
>>> string3 = "I have rice rice rice, soup, vegetable for lunch"
>>> make_regex(string1).pattern
'I have (?P<food1>.*), (?P<food2>.*), (?P<food3>.*) for lunch'
>>> find_mappings(string1, string2)
{'food1': 'rice', 'food3': 'vegetable', 'food2': 'soup'}
>>> find_mappings(string1, string3)
{'food1': 'rice rice rice', 'food3': 'vegetable', 'food2': 'soup'}
```

Note that this can handle non alpha numeric tokens (see `food1` and `rice rice rice`). Obviously this will probably do an awful lot of backtracking and might be slow. You can tweak the `.*` regex to try and make it faster depending on your expectations on "tokens".

---

For production ready code you'd want to `re.escape` the parts outside the `(?P<name>.*)` groups. A bit of pain in the ass to do because you have to "split" that string and call `re.escape` on each piece, put them together and call `re.compile`.

---

Since my answer got accepted I wanted to include a more robust version of the regex:

```
def make_regex(text):
    regex = ''.join(map(extract_and_escape, re.split(r'\$\(', text)))
    return re.compile(regex)

def extract_and_escape(partial_text):
    m = re.match(r'(\w+)\)', partial_text)
    if m:
        group_name = m.group(1)
        return ('(?P<%s>.*)' % group_name) + re.escape(partial_text[len(group_name)+1:])
    return re.escape(partial_text)
```

This avoids issues when the text contains special regex characters (e.g. `I have $(food1) and it costs $$$`. The first solution would end up considering `$$$` as three times the `$` anchor (which would fail), this robust solution escapes them.

Answer (score 5):

I think this can be cleanly done with regex-based splitting. This should also handle punctuation and other special characters (where a split on space is not enough).

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'[^\w$()]+')
mapping = {
    x[2:-1]: y for x, y in zip(p.split(string1), p.split(string2)) if x != y}
```

For your examples, this returns

```
{'fruit': 'apple'}
```

and

```
{'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'soup', 'food3': 'vegetable'}
```

Comment: Depending on what kind of interpolated variables are used, this might not work. For instance, if `$(food-1)` is used, it will not return the correct result.  Can you go into the limitations of this solution?

Comment: @Ruzihm Fair point, this mostly won't work unless the tokens are alphanumeric.

Comment: This is really neat. Extremely simple, but effective for the simple cases and also quite efficient. My solution is a bit more general, would still require a bit of tweaking to make it robust and is probably much slower in any case...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this does the trick.

```
s_1 = 'I had $(food_1), $(food_2) and $(food_3) for lunch'
s_2 = 'I had rice, meat and vegetable for lunch'

result = {}
for elem1, elem2 in zip(s_1.split(), s_2.split()):
    if elem1.startswith('$'):
        result[elem1.strip(',')[2:-1]] = elem2
print result
# {'food_3': 'vegetable', 'food_2': 'meat', 'food_1': 'rice,'}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same. I also like to avoid regex at almost all cost, so +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> dict((x.strip('$(),'),y.strip(',')) for x,y in zip(string1.split(), string2.split()) if x!=y)
{'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'soup', 'food3': 'vegetable'}
```

Or with a regex:

```
>>> import re 
>>> dict((x, y) for x,y in zip(re.findall(r'\w+', string1), re.findall(r'\w+', string2)) if x!=y)
{'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'soup', 'food3': 'vegetable'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not use regex:

```
string1 = "I have $(food1), $(food2), $(food3) for lunch"
string2 = "I have rice, soup, vegetable for lunch"
trans_table = str.maketrans({'$': '', '(': '', ')': '', ',': ''})
{
    substr1.translate(trans_table): substr2.translate(trans_table)
    for substr1, substr2 in zip(string1.split(),string2.split())
    if substr1 != substr2
}
```

Output:

```
{'food1': 'rice', 'food2': 'soup', 'food3': 'vegetable'}
```

Alternatively, something a bit more flexible:

```
def substr_parser(substr, chars_to_ignore='$(),'):
    trans_table = str.maketrans({char: '' for char in chars_to_ignore})
    substr = substr.translate(trans_table)
    # More handling here
    return substr

{
    substr_parser(substr1): substr_parser(substr2)
    for substr1, substr2 in zip(string1.split(),string2.split())
    if substr1 != substr2
}
```

Same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
def get_dict(a, b):
  keys, values = re.findall('(?<=\$\().*?(?=\))', a), re.findall(re.sub('\$\(.*?\)', '(\w+)', a), b)
  return dict(zip(keys, values if not isinstance(_values[0], tuple) else _values[0]))

d = [["I love to eat $(fruit)", "I love to eat apple"], ["I have $(food1), $(food2), $(food3) for lunch", "I have rice, soup, vegetable for lunch"]]
results = [get_dict(*i) for i in d]
```

Output:

```
[{'fruit': 'apple'}, {'food3': 'vegetable', 'food2': 'soup', 'food1': 'rice'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` in combination with `dictionary comprehension` works well here we can `zip` the two lists and only take the pairs that are not equal.

```
l = [*zip(s1.split(),s2.split())]
d = {i[0].strip('$(),'): i[1] for i in l if i[0] != i[1] }
```